# Prolog: tuple|dict unification : partial match?

Tags: prolog, tuples, partial, unification

is there a way to do partial unification of tuples :

```
?- (_,c: X, _) = ( w: 23, c: 10, p: 45 ).
X = 10.

?- (c: X, _) = ( w: 23, c: 10, p: 45 ).
false.

?- (c: X) = ( w: 23, c: 10, p: 45 ).
false.
```

only the first works. I want the third example to work ?

prepend-atom , does not work either, if the keys are not in exact order :

```
?- (_,w: X, p: Y, _) = (blah , w: 23, c: 10, p: 45 ).
false.
```

I would also like it to unify in the rule head , f.e.

```
rule((c: X)) :- X < 10.
rule((w: X, p: Y)) :- X < 10, Y > 0.
```

The reason is that i dont know the content of the tuple I just know that it has element with "key"  - "c" or "w"-and-"p", or any combination in no particular order.

---

SWI-Prolog dicts work, but I don't know how to do partial match in  a rule()-head ?!

```
 ?- _{c: X, a: Y} >:< _{ a: 5, b: 4, c:12, d:18}.
 X = 12,
 Y = 5.
```

but rule-matching by default does full-unification i.e:

```
 ?- _{c: X, a: Y} = _{ a: 5, b: 4, c:12, d:18}.
 false.
```

Comment: Several ways. Just add one or two underscores after left bracket, or use `member/2` (or `select/3` if you want to do error-checking also).

Comment: how do u do it in rule-head ?

Comment: If it is always three, you can have a pattern `(A,B,C)`.

Comment: .it is unknown number of kv pairs, with unknown keys..

Comment: Then just have one variable in the head.